# I would like to hide the discount input field on our checkout page. Using checkout UI extensions

Tags: shopify, checkout, shopify-app, reduction

Shopify's ui extensibility seems really powerful and flexible. But I would like to know if there is any way to add a custom CSS or js file in Checkout UI extension. To be particular, I would like to hide the discount input field on our checkout page. I tried to figure out the checkout UI extensions, but I am new to this field. Please reply to this comment, if anyone has a solution to it. thank you.
Tried chekout ui extensibility, shopify function, branding api, but didnt find solution to target already exist field.

I tried to figure out the checkout UI extensions, but I am new to this field. Please reply to this comment, if anyone has a solution to it. thank you.
Tried chekout ui extensibility, shopify function, branding api, but didnt find solution to target already exist field.